# How to delete a table record from accumulo?

Tags: accumulo

How can I delete an accumulo record from accumulo shell?

I have a table geomesa - and there are records that are corresponded the index tables. One of index tables are disappeared. I needed to remove that orphans records. But I can't. I can't find any example how to delete an accumulo record from shell.

In shell I tried to delete record by key but I can't understand what I needed to delete it.

```
root@accumulo> delete myNamespace.geomesa_SignalBuilder_z3_geo_time_v7_02734
2022-05-30 21:42:56,519 [shell.Shell] ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected 3 arguments. There was 1.
usage: delete <row> <colfamily> <colqualifier> [-?] [-l <expression>] [--timeout <timeout>] [-ts <timestamp>]
description: deletes a record from a table
  -?,--help                              display this help
  -l,--visibility-label <expression>     formatted visibility
     --timeout <timeout>                 time before insert should fail if no data is written. If no unit is given assumes seconds. Units d,h,m,s,and ms are supported. e.g. 30s or 100ms
  -ts,--timestamp <timestamp>            timestamp to use for deletion
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

show all namespace tables

> tables -ns myNamespace

then choose a table geomesa:

> table myNamespace.geomesa

look at records of this table

> scan

delete found records in this table

> deletemany -r SignalBuilder~table.z2.geo.v5.02734 -f

apply changes

> flush